# Manipulate an XML file with FAKE

Tags: f#, windows-phone-8.1, f#-fake

Question: How do I set a specific attribute in an XML file with FAKE?

I want to build a Windows Phone 8.1 project with the help of FAKE. The version tag is a parameter of the build script. The tag is already baked into the assemply info:

```
let version = getBuildParamOrDefault "version" "0.0.0.1"

Target "AssemblyInfo" (fun _ ->
    CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo "./src/SharedAssemblyInfo.cs"  
        [
            Attribute.Product     product
            Attribute.Version     version
            Attribute.FileVersion version
            Attribute.Metadata    ("githash", commitHash)
        ]
)
```

There is another file in a Windows Phone 8.1 project that contains version information: Package.appxmanifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package ...>

    <Identity Name="..." Publisher="..." Version="1.0.0.0" />

    ...

</Package>
```

I want to change the value of the Version attribute of the Identity tag. It should contain the version tag given as build parameter. I want to do it in a separate target with the name "AppxManifest" and it should execute after manipulating the assembly info file but before the MSBuild build is executed:

```
Target "AppxManifest" (fun _ ->

    ???

)

"Clean"
==> "RestorePackages"
==> "AssemblyInfo"
==> "AppxManifest"
==> "Build"
```

I have found an XMLHelper in the documentation of FAKE (http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-xmlhelper.html) and it looks like that this thing can do the job. But there are no examples. I could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the XMLHelper library to manipulate XML files. The function XmlPoke can be used to change an element in an XML file by referenceing it with an XPath expression. The Package.appxmanifest file contains namespaces, therefore you have to take the sister function XmlPokeNS which can handle namespaces properly.

The last difficulty is the default namespace in Package.appxmanifest. You have to specify a prefix which you associate with the default namespace. In your XPath expression this prefix is used to reference the XML elements.

There is no special prefix string, you can choose whatever you want. In this example I choose the prefix "df":

```
open Fake.XMLHelper

Target "PackageAppxmanifest" <| fun _ ->
    let file = "<path to Package.appxmanifest>"
    let ns = [ "df", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest" ]
    let xpath = @"df:Package/df:Identity/@Version"
    XmlPokeNS file ns xpath version
```